# Relationship between blood pressure time series and ventricular dynamics of the heart

Tags: cardiology, blood-pressure, electrocardiography

The answer to this question is probably very straightforward, but I have actually had some difficulty finding an explicit answer online.

To what extent does the oscillatory pattern of arterial blood pressure (over small increments in time) mirror the oscillatory pattern of heart beat. For simplicity, imagine my heart beat signal is a binary signal where 0 means blood is not being ejected and 1 means blood is being ejected into circulation.

Said differently, if I detect a transient (where the interval of time is less than one second) increase in arterial pressure (e.g. a local peak), can I always accurately map that event to the "causal" contraction of the ventricles during blood ejection?

Similarly, can I use an arterial blood pressure time series to accurately recreate the binary signal of the heart beat? (Though, perhaps there will be a slight time shift due to the propagation speed of a pressure wave).

To provide another silly example: if my arterial pressure time series has 60 peaks (and corresponding "separating troughs"), can I confidently assert that the heart beat 60 times?

Comment: What happens when you take a pulse?

Comment: @BryanKrause ehhh. I was hoping for a legitimate paper. Taking a radial pulse is likely a grandfathered in practice that predates technology from the past 50+ years...I'm reluctant to claim something as canonical in the absence of quantitative evidence. I did not know if there was some paper that simultaneously measured time series of a ventricular valves open/close states and an arbitrary artery's vessel pressure. Certainly the radial pulse can be used as a proxy for heart beat (that's why it's a grandfathered in practice) but can it capture ectopic heart beats that eject very little blood?

Comment: Be careful not to ask an "XY" question. If you want to ask about ectopic heart beats then *ask about that* rather than the vague question you wrote here.